# How to disable Spring Boot Hibernate "Listing entities" option?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

We have a Spring Boot RESTful web app. Whenever data is submitted to an endpoint, the log is completely filled with data that represents the state of the database entities involved in the submission process.

Looking in the Log I see this:

```
2019-11-01 10:50:44.686 DEBUG [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-2] o.h.i.u.EntityPrinter [EntityPrinter.java:102] Listing entities:
```

And then **every entity involved in the traction** is printed out ... even the binary data for images and such.

I know it is a DEBUG statement, but there has got to be a way to be in DEBUG mode and not get all that useless data printed to the log. How can I do this, how can I turn off the "Listing entities" feature?

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your application in `DEBUG` log level mode?

Try setting the log level of package `org.hibernate.internal.util` to `INFO` in your `application.yml` file.

```
logging:
    level:
        org.hibernate.internal.util: INFO
```

The log in question is generated by class `EntityPrinter` ([source](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/util/EntityPrinter.java)) belonging to package `org.hibernate.internal.util` as part of below overridden implementation of `toString()` method.

```
public void toString(Iterable<Map.Entry<EntityKey, Object>> entitiesByEntityKey) throws HibernateException {
        if ( !LOG.isDebugEnabled() || !entitiesByEntityKey.iterator().hasNext() ) {
            return;
        }

        LOG.debug( "Listing entities:" );
        int i = 0;
        for ( Map.Entry<EntityKey, Object> entityKeyAndEntity : entitiesByEntityKey ) {
            if ( i++ > 20 ) {
                LOG.debug( "More......" );
                break;
            }
            LOG.debug( toString( entityKeyAndEntity.getKey().getEntityName(), entityKeyAndEntity.getValue() ) );
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am running in DEBUG, but I don't want all of that. Maybe the strings or integers/doubles/floats/etc., but not the binary data.